# css: left nav scrolling

Tags: html, css

Left panel and main content should scroll individually.

Following is fiddle for that.

http://plnkr.co/edit/Le6hPWwMm0pu5Ukm2cYg?p=preview

Following is css for that

```
html {
overflow-y: scroll;
}


body {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
overflow-x: hidden;
font-family: Arial;
font-size: 18px;
position:fixed;
overflow-y:auto;
}


header {
background-color: #3b5998;
padding: 10px;
text-decoration: none;
position: fixed;
width: 100%;
z-index: 1;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 3px 7px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
box-shadow: 0px 3px 7px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}


 #content {
background-color: #FFFFFF;
padding: 52px 10px 10px 10px;
position: relative;
width: auto;
height: 100%;
-webkit-box-shadow: -10px 0px 9px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
box-shadow: -10px 0px 9px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
overflow-y:auto;
 }

 #hamburger {
border: 1px solid #374C77;
border-radius: 3px 3px 3px 3px;
cursor: pointer;
display: block;
height: 24px;
padding: 3px 4px 3px;
position: relative;
width: 25px;
background: #4569b2;
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #4569b2 0%, #4062a5 100%);
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #4569b2), color-stop(100%, #4062a5));
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #4569b2 0%, #4062a5 100%);
background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #4569b2 0%, #4062a5 100%);
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #4569b2 0%, #4062a5 100%);
background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #4569b2 0%, #4062a5 100%);
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#4569b2', endColorstr='#4062a5', GradientType=0);
 }

#hamburger div {
background-color: #fff;
border: 1px solid #eee;
border-radius: 2px 2px 2px 2px;
height: 2px;
margin-top: 3px;
width: 90%;
 }


nav {
opacity: 0;
left: 0px;
top: 0px;
position: fixed;
z-index: 0;
width: 70%;
height: 100%;
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
box-sizing: border-box;
overflow-x: hidden;
overflow-y: auto;
background: #3e3c3d;
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #3e3c3d 0%, #2d2c2d 100%);
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #3e3c3d), color-stop(100%, #2d2c2d));
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #3e3c3d 0%, #2d2c2d 100%);
background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #3e3c3d 0%, #2d2c2d 100%);
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #3e3c3d 0%, #2d2c2d 100%);
background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #3e3c3d 0%, #2d2c2d 100%);
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#3e3c3d', endColorstr='#2d2c2d', GradientType=0);
}
```

main content is not at all moving. Left panel and main content should move independently

Answer (score 0):

Just remove this line from body

```
position:fixed;
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/gmZSXYUu4aWMF4eAkewR

**Edited Again**

Make header's position relative.

```
position:relative;
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/WqLFqtgZwkQA5vs3TUD9

Comment: If i do that then while scrolling menu body also scrolls

Comment: after removing positio fixed from body and header both left nav menu is not at all opening

Comment: Edited again, check now

Comment: Left panel and main content should move independently. They are if we scroll left navigation menu then body is also moving

Comment: It's working fine for me. When you drag down the left menu, the menu stays still. When you slide down the main body, the left menu stays on it's place. Here you can see http://run.plnkr.co/gCyWHYmJ4xOP0jMt/